# When to roll during spellcasting?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dice

I have played a few games of D&D with my equally as inexperienced friends and there are some uncertainties we have about spells that I would like to clarify before I take my turn to DM.

When exactly do you have to roll for spells and how much. We've had a mix of casting rolls, then later additionally had to roll attack rolls for some spells, followed then by having to roll saving throws and occasionally some dodging rolls if the scenario required (sort of rare). These are a lot of points of failure for spellcasting and it felt like spellcasters were effectively pacing well-behind melee and rogue classes for dpr. We didn't even include concentration  to keep a spell casted and since our last DM was inexperienced we sort of had war-casting all around but they still seemed to pace behind.

My question is: When someone casts a spell, what are all the dice rolls he will have to usually do? Do you only roll an attack die or saving throw dice?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad - the way to answer this is by reading the chapter on spellcasting.

Comment: Have you read the spellcasting chapter in the PHB? Can you make it clear to us exactly what is unclear about it and what you're having trouble understanding so that we might better be able to provide you with the answer you're looking for?

Comment: @Miniman I don't see how a question that can be answered in 3-5 sentences is too broad.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I had read through it but there was another player who was slightly more expereienced than us and he said that we should basically never expect to not roll the dice for a spell. For example, I had to roll to cast Light spells. I hadn't been able to find any section listed in the book so that's why I came to talk with others here.

Comment: @Skyler That's the point - it can't be answered in 3-5 sentences. SevenSidedDie's answer is 3 paragraphs and it *still* doesn't cover everything your question needs to be fully explained. You need to read the PHB, not ask "Please explain this whole chapter".

Comment: @Skyler I would also suggest getting the other player to (re)read the spellcasting chapter. I'm sure there are a number of spells that don't require *any* roll *whatsoever.*

Comment: @PurpleMonkey "a number of spells that don't require any roll whatsoever" - eg, Light

Answer (score 3):

You roll the dice the spell says to roll, no more or less. As a *general* pattern within the design of D&D 5e spellcasting, a spell will call for either an attack roll *or* a saving throw, but not both. The specific spell will tell you which, if any, rolls are required. Most spells that are not combat-related (and even a few that are) require no rolls at all — they just work.

Additionally, concentration does not involve rolls, but it sounds like you might be somehow thinking it does. Concentration is just a way to limit certain kinds of spells — you can't have more than one ongoing spell that requires concentration at the same time — and isn't a requirement to make some kind of “concentration roll” every time. (If you're being hit, then you do have to roll to maintain concentration; but if your spellcasters are being hit often enough for that to be a problem, they're way too close to the fight!) If you've played earlier editions of D&D, you might be importing the idea of a concentration roll when no such thing exists in D&D 5e.

I don't know what kind of “dodging rolls” you've encountered during play, but there generally aren't such things in D&D. The concept of dodging is usually already baked into the AC needed for an attack to hit, and is not rolled separately. Otherwise, some Dexterity-based saving throws exist where reflexes matter, but they're not special “dodge” rolls, and they're not going to be in addition to another saving throw, just the only saving throw (if at all). If the idea of a “dodge roll” in your game is a mistake or a house rule, it could be impacting spellcasters negatively, yes.

Comment: @nitsua60 Yes, that's possibly what they mean. I assumed they weren't being hit enough for that to be relevant, but that would be assuming the D&D tactics of a veteran!

Comment: So for example, if someone activates Call Lightning the only rolls ever done are the DM rolling saving throws and the players damage dice.

Comment: @Skyler Well, if an NPC cast the spell on the player characters it'd be the other way around, but yes. There's generally no roll to cast light, for instance, because the light spell description does not specify the need for a roll under normal circumstances.